# what does this mean "order by NULL"

Tags: sql, oracle11g

i use oracle 11g.what does the line order by null means in the following

```
select f_value,row_number() over (order by null) as id 
from tableName"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `OVER()` clause for `ROW_NUMBER()` requires an `ORDER BY`

using `ORDER BY NULL` is a **workaround** that satifies the syntax requirement but does not actually change the order of the data. In effect it is an instruction to not order at all.

**N.B.**: some (myself included) prefer to use `SELECT 1` instead of `SELECT NULL` but there is no difference in effect.

Bottom line: not great, but it works.

---

tip: TSQL does not permit the direct use of SELECT 1, but you may use (SELECT 1)

Comment: so,if i m using something like row_number over (order by COLUMN_NAME) will sort the row_number column based on the given column.is it?

Comment: yes, absolutely. You can "PARTITION BY" and "ORDER BY" inside the OVER() - partition by is similar to group by - it controls where row_number() restarts counting at 1