# What does LISTAGG with ORDER BY NULL actually use as the order criteria?

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by, listagg

If I do

```
SELECT LISTAGG( COLUMN_VALUE ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY NULL )   AS OrderByNULL,
       LISTAGG( COLUMN_VALUE ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY 1 )      AS OrderByCONST,
       LISTAGG( COLUMN_VALUE ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS OrderByROWNUM
FROM   TABLE( SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST( '5', '222', '4' ) );
```

The output is:

```
ORDERBYNULL ORDERBYCONST ORDERBYROWNUM
----------- ------------ -------------
222,4,5     222,4,5      5,222,4
```

The query appears to have done an alphanumerical sort when using `ORDER BY` with non-deterministic ordering (`NULL` or a constant) and has maintained the input order when using `ORDER BY ROWNUM` (deterministic).

The [`LISTAGG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) documentation states that:

> The order_by_clause determines the order in which the concatenated values are returned. The function is deterministic only if the ORDER BY column list achieved unique ordering.

And when looking at [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) it states that:

> Whenever the order_by_clause results in identical values for multiple rows, the function behaves as follows: [...] For all other analytic functions, the result depends on the window specification. If you specify a logical window with the RANGE keyword, then the function returns the same result for each of the rows. If you specify a physical window with the ROWS keyword, then the result is nondeterministic.

So as far as I can tell from the documentation a non-deterministic ordering is to be expected - however, the function gives a deterministic output based on an alphanumerical sort and not on the order in which the rows are processed (which is the [commonly held view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377014/what-does-this-mean-order-by-null)).

This is different to the behaviour of other analytic functions (when using a physical window with the `ROWS` keyword):

```
SELECT LAST_VALUE( COLUMN_VALUE )
         OVER ( ORDER BY NULL   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING )
         AS BYNULL,
       LAST_VALUE( COLUMN_VALUE )
         OVER ( ORDER BY 1      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING )
         AS BYCONST,
       LAST_VALUE( COLUMN_VALUE )
         OVER ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING )
         AS BYROWNUM
FROM   TABLE( SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST( '5', '222', '4' ) );
```

Which gives a consistent output for all the different orderings:

```
BYNULL BYCONST BYROWNUM
------ ------- --------
4      4       4
4      4       4
4      4       4
```

**Is there official documentation for how an ordering is applied when `LISTAGG` is supplied a non-deterministic ordering?**

Note: The behaviour of `ORDER BY NULL` is commented on [here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=515) stating:

> In this example, the elements have been aggregated alphabetically, despite the NULL ordering clause. This appears to be the default behaviour when using a constant ORDER BY expression

But this is just an comment on the behaviour in a non-Oracle site.

Comment: One set of results provides basically zero evidence of determinism.  If you use a constant or `NULL`, then expect the results in any order.  The documentation is quite clear that you cannot rely on the ordering when the `order by` keys have the same values.

Comment: However, if you repeat the test (with different data) you will consistently get the same alphanumeric ordering. How many sets of results do you need for this ordering to be considered a design feature rather than co-incidence?

Comment: Whatever it's doing seems to ignore NLS_COMP/SORT. Presumably it's an implementation detail. rather than a design feature - and so doesn't seem to be documented, including on MOS. And as such, is not something you can rely on - since it could change in a future release? It's interesting, but not sure if it's useful.

Comment: @AlexPoole . . . It is also possible that the results would be out-of-order on a parallel system or with large amounts of data.

Comment: Just because the current implementation, for your sample, seems to behave deterministically, does not mean that all samples in all versions, on all operating systems, will also behave deterministically, or even in a similar fashion.

Comment: @YogoZuno Which was entirely the point of asking the question - is there any documentation of `LISTAGG`'s implementation (which appears to apply an undocumented deterministic ordering when the `ORDER BY` clause is non-deterministic) that supersedes the generic documentation of the analytic functions which state the order should be non-deterministic?

Comment: @MT0, it may be that it's sorting them asciibetically in this case.  However, Oracle reserves the right to change how it does so in the future, as many, MANY developers learned when Oracle implemented hash aggregation as well as sort aggregation, and many SQL statements that used to get sorting "for free" no longer did.  The rule of thumb for Oracle tables - even those only in memory, cast from a list, is that they are of ORGANIZATION HEAP unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the order will depend on many factor, including the execution plan of the query, the configuration of your instance, the version of the database, if you are on exadata or not.

If you are not giving oracle any specific criteria to order the data you can't count on any specific ordering, even if from your trials you seem to get the data consistently sorted in a specific way.

According to [Oracle documentation for listagg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030):

- The order_by_clause determines the order in which the concatenated values are returned. The function is deterministic only if the ORDER BY column list achieved unique ordering.