# Group query rows result in one result

Tags: sql, oracle

I need make a query that I get the result and put in one line separated per comma.

For example, I have this query:

```
SELECT 
   SIGLA
FROM
 LANGUAGES
```

This query return the result below:

**SIGLA**

```
ESP
EN
BRA
```

I need to get this result in one single line that way:

**SIGLA**

```
ESP,EN,BRA
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SELECT LISTAGG( SIGLA,  ',' )   within group (order by SIGLA) as NewSigla FROM LANGUAGES
```

Comment: You didn't do the full LISTAGG syntax?

    SELECT LISTAGG(SIGLA, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SIGLA) " As "S_List" 
    FROM LANGUAGES

Comment: `ORA-02000: missing WITHIN keyword`

Comment: I had to use this way:

SELECT LISTAGG(SIGLA, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SIGLA) "SIGLAS" FROM LANGUAGES

But your answer help me as a base to find solutions. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT LISTAGG(SIGLA, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SIGLA) " As "S_List" FROM LANGUAGES
```

Should be the listagg sequence you are needing

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the values grouped together in the order that Oracle produces the rows then:

```
SELECT LISTAGG( SIGLA, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS SIGLA
FROM   LANGUAGES;
```

If you want alphabetical ordering then replace `ORDER BY ROWNUM` with `ORDER BY SIGLA` (or, [curiously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747417/what-does-listagg-with-order-by-null-actually-use-as-the-order-criteria), `ORDER BY NULL`).