# Oracle SQL comma-separated id

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, listagg

I have a query like so:

```
SELECT
  s.id,
  CASE
    WHEN INSTR(s.strain_value, '[') = 0
    THEN s.strain_name
    ELSE TRIM(SUBSTR(s.strain_name, 1, INSTR(s.strain_name, '[')-1))
  END AS strain_name
FROM strain s
```

This gives me a table that looks like:

```
id      strain_name
----------------------------------------------
100     CD-1
101     CD-1
102     CD-1
200     SCID
300     BusIp-hy
301     BusIp-hy
...     ...
```

Now I wanted to group the resulting table by the `strain_name` and get the comma-separated `id` like the following:

```
id              strain_name
----------------------------------------------
100, 101, 102   CD-1
200             SCID
300, 301        BusIp-hy
...             ...
```

I tried this query out but I'm not getting what I wanted:

```
WITH q AS (
  SELECT
    s.id,
    CASE
      WHEN INSTR(s.strain_name, '[') = 0
      THEN s.strain_name
      ELSE TRIM(SUBSTR(s.strain_name, 1, INSTR(s.strain_name, '[')-1))
    END AS strain_name
  FROM strain s
)
SELECT (
  SELECT LISTAGG(id, ', ')
  WITHIN GROUP (
    ORDER BY strain_name ASC
  )
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT strain_name FROM q) dc
) AS id, strain_name
FROM q
```

Can you please help me correct the last query so that I can get a comma-separated list of the `id` for each `strain_name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH q ( id, strain_name ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         CASE WHEN INSTR(strain_value, '[') = 0
              THEN strain_name
              ELSE TRIM(SUBSTR(strain_name, 1, INSTR(strain_name, '[')-1))
         END
  FROM strain
)
SELECT LISTAGG( id, ', ' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY id ) AS id,
       strain_name
FROM   q
GROUP BY strain_name
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. Just wondering though why you had to change the `ORDER BY` from `strain_name` to `id`?

Comment: @PatrickGregorio From your expected results it appears you want to have the comma-separated ids in ascending order. The `ORDER BY` for the `LISTAGG` is within the group so all the items will have the same `strain_name` (since that is the group by clause) - using that as the order will result in a [non-deterministic ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35747417/1509264) but the `id` values appear to all be different and so will result in a deterministic ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried GROUP BY?

```
WITH q AS (
...
)
SELECT strain_name, listagg(id, ', ') within GROUP(ORDER BY id)
FROM   q
GROUP  BY strain_name
ORDER  BY strain_name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH q AS (
  SELECT
    s.id,
    CASE
      WHEN INSTR(s.strain_name, '[') = 0
      THEN s.strain_name
      ELSE TRIM(SUBSTR(s.strain_name, 1, INSTR(s.strain_name, '[')-1))
    END AS strain_name
  FROM strain s
)
SELECT LISTAGG(id, ', ')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id ASC) as id, q.strain_name
  FROM q
group by q.strain_name
```