# Oracle Regex - Remove duplicates including chinese

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, duplicates

I'm trying to remove the duplicates in the results of a query involving listagg.
I'm using this syntax:

```
 REGEXP_REPLACE (LISTAGG (PR.NAME, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1),
                 '([^,]+)(,\1)+',
                 '\1') AS PRODUCERS
```

However, occurrences including chinese characters are not removed:

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: Please put your data as text - not as image.

Comment: Looks like there is something else, [the regex works](http://rextester.com/RNTE84607).

Comment: The query relies on [undocumented behaviour of `LISTAGG` when ordering by a constant value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35747417/1509264) (TL;DR the documented behaviour is that, in this case, the order by should be non-deterministic but `LISTAGG` applies an undocumented alphabetical sort) and if this ever stops using alphabetical sort then the regular expression will break. You would be better making the sort explicit and using `ORDER BY PR.NAME`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No - it doesn't work [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8bda6/6)

Comment: @MT0 That code does not work, the regex does.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, it is replacing sub-strings of elements - so if the `LISTAGG` gives the output `A,A,AA` then the regular expression will match the first 2½ elements and give the output `AA` when it should only match the first 2 elements and give the output `A,AA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression does not work. If the `LISTAGG` output is `A,A,AA` then the regular expression `([^,]+)(,\1)+` does not check that it has matched a complete element of your list and will match `A,A,A` which is 2½ elements of the list and will give the output `AA` instead of the expected `A,AA`. Worse, if you have the string `BA,BABAB,BABD` then the regular expression will replace `BA,BA` with `BA` and then replace `BAB,BAB` with `BAB` and you end up with the string `BABABD` which does not match any of the elements of the original list.

An example demonstrating this is:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa6bf7/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE names ( id, name ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'AA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 'BA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 'A' FROM DUAL
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (
         LISTAGG (NAME, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1),
         '([^,]+)(,\1)+',
         '\1'
       ) AS constant_sort
FROM   names
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa6bf7/1/0)**:

```
| CONSTANT_SORT |
|---------------|
|       AA,BA,C |
```

If you want to get the distinct elements then you can use `DISTINCT` (as per [Littlefoot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49424283/1509264)) or you can [`COLLECT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions031.htm#SQLRF06304) the values into a user-defined collection and then use the [`SET` function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions177.htm#SQLRF06308) to remove duplicates. You can then pass this de-duplicated collection to a table collection expression and use `LISTAGG` to get your output:

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE StringList IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000)
/
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT (
         SELECT LISTAGG( column_value, ',' )
                  WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM )
         FROM   TABLE( n.unique_names )
       ) AS agg_names
FROM   (
  SELECT SET( CAST( COLLECT( name ORDER BY NAME ) AS StringList ) )
           AS unique_names
  FROM   names
) n
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa6bf7/1/1)**:

```
|   AGG_NAMES |
|-------------|
| A,AA,B,BA,C |
```

Regarding your comment:

> in the context of a bigger query involving a lot of join and given my begginers skills I would have no idea how to implement this model

For example, if your query was:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         LISTAGG (PR.NAME, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1),
         '([^,]+)(,\1)+',
         '\1'
       ) AS PRODUCERS,
       other_column1,
       other_column2
FROM   table1 pr
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON (pr.some_condition = t2.some_condition )
WHERE  t2.some_other_condition = 'TRUE'
GROUP BY other_column1, other_column2
```

Then you can change it to:

```
SELECT (
         SELECT LISTAGG( COLUMN_VALUE, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM )
         FROM   TABLE( t.PRODUCERS )
       ) AS producers,
       other_column1,
       other_column2
FROM   (
  SELECT SET( CAST( COLLECT( PR.name ORDER BY PR.NAME ) AS StringList ) )
           AS PRODUCERS,
         other_column1,
         other_column2
  FROM   table1 pr
         INNER JOIN table2 t2
         ON (pr.some_condition = t2.some_condition )
  WHERE  t2.some_other_condition = 'TRUE'
  GROUP BY other_column1, other_column2
) t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailled answer, but in the context of a bigger query involving a lot of join and given my begginers skills I would have no idea how to implement this model

Comment: @Marc Updated with an example of how to integrate it into a large query.

Comment: Thanks so much for the time you took to provide me with this example, I managed to get something working

Answer (score 0):

(I can't see images; company policy).

Why wouldn't you remove duplicates *before* applying LISTAGG? Something like

```
select listagg(x.distinct_name, ',') within group (order by 1) producers
from (select DISTINCT name distinct_name
      from some_table
     ) x
```

Comment: Because this is only part of a bigger query with multiple join

Comment: @Marc even if that is the case, you can use the bigger query as a subquery and wrap `SELECT DISTINCT` around it, then use `LISTAGG()` on that result.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to remove duplicates is to use window functions and `case`:

```
select listagg(case when seqnum = 1 then name end, ',') within group (order by 1) as producers
from (select . . .,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by name) as seqnum
      from . . .
     ) t
```

This does require modifications to the rest of the query, but you should still be able to do the rest of the aggregations and computations.